# Nuxtjs/Toast and custom icons

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Is it possible to add an icon into the message of a toast error or do I need to install a different/another module?
I'm using vue and trying to add a component as an icon at the moment but not having any luck.

```
this.$toast.error('<icon-paperclip />')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-toasted#methods) it's written that you can pass either `String` or `HTML`.

Since a Vue component is a bit more than that, you will probably not be able to pass it directly.

Meanwhile, you could probably look for some HTML icon and inline it here.